# Import only latest changes from MYSQL dump file when importing

Tags: mysql, database, performance, import

When importing a MySQL dump file from the staging server database to my local database it's taking too much time, is there any way that only the latest changes which are not there in the current local DB would be imported from the new dump file.

Comment: No such way. Import all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not supplied complete info.  How big is the table?  Are you replacing the entire table?  Multiple tables?  Are there `FOREIGN KEYs`?  Are you worried about blocking activity?  What does "latest" mean?

If you are completely replacing one table (no FKs):

1. Load the new data into a *separate* table.
2. `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;`
3. `DROP TABLE old;`

That won't speed things up, but will virtually eliminate any interference with the running table.

It is possible to 'incrementally' update a table.

1. Load the new data into a *separate* table.
2. `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` (3 separate queries) the new rows into the table.  Use a `SELECT ... LEFT JOIN` to see which rows are "new/changed/gone".

If you provide more details about your ultimate goals, I may have more details/tips.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Yes there are multiple tables that need to be updated and there are foreign keys too, as for the size, one table could have 10000+ rows and 50+ columns, and in the database, there are a total of 140 tables.

Comment: The table size is only a few megabytes?  The entire database is only 1GB or so?  What kind of disk is involved (HDD vs SSD)?  What do you mean by "too much time"?  Which statement is running most of the time?

Comment: The table size is only a few megabytes: Yes,
The entire database is only 1GB or so: Dump file is Size of 1.8Gb,
What kind of disk is involved (HDD vs SSD): HDD,
What do you mean by "too much time": 40Min,
Which statement is running most of the time: Don't know exactly

Comment: @akshayrathi - 40min for 1.8GB, even on HDD seems high.  More questions:  RAM size, Engine used, the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.